# How to turn table record into link?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

The easiest example of this is within stackoverflow.  If you click my username where ever it's displayed - you will see my user info page with posts, etc.  I am trying to do something similar.  Currently I have a page to view all posts made by the current user.  I also have created a page to view all posts by the selected user(clicking the link).    I'm attempting to wrap a @html.displayfor with an @html.actionlink.  So far it isn't working.  Here is my view with wrapping attempt.

```
    <td href="@Html.ActionLink("SelectedUserPosts", "Subtopic", new { UserId = item.UserId }) ">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.FirstName)
    </td>
```

and here is my controller method.

```
    public ActionResult SelectedUserPosts(int UserId)
    {
        int UserID = UserId;
        SubTopic subTopic = db.SubTopics.Where(t => t.UserId == UserID);
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your object to your view.

```
public ActionResult SelectedUserPosts(int UserId)
{
    int UserID = UserId;
    SubTopic subTopic = db.SubTopics.Where(t => t.UserId == UserID);
    return View(subTopic);
}
```

See MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View%28System.Object%29

Comment: I apologize I had taken the object out when testing a different method.  I have two big main issues.  The first is that my userid within subtopic is a string.  Is userid within identity an integer or string?  I'm also running into an issue with the actionlink where it cuts off at the 2nd " after selecteduserposts and puts the rest in the view.  Thank you for your help though